# How to get cURL to work on windows?

Tags: php, curl, xampp

I have tried several times now to get cURL to work using xampp, whith no success. First I tried using http://www.tonyspencer.com/2003/10/22/curl-with-php-and-apache-on-windows/

Then http://chrismeller.com/2007/04/using-curl-in-xampp

And several other web posts, still I keep getting the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 4

I have unquoted the line: **extension=php_curl.dll** in php.ini, and restarted apache SEVERAL times, still the I get that error! Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) (Also found in XAMPP at http://localhost/) shows that cURL has loaded correctly. If you are not using a fresh install, consider doing so. If XAMPP is not a requirement, consider trying [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). I used XAMPP for several years before switching to this on Windows and MAMP on Mac. It's a single click to start things and I didn't have as many issues as when I was using XAMPP.

Comment: I just tried that and I still get the same error :(
Any other sugestions?